# How to configure CouchDB from my nodejs app

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to create a self-hosted app. This app would provide a custom express server with some routes and also provides a CouchDB access using [pouchdb-server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server). I would like the node server to be able to configure the database and create the admin username/password, and then create the roles functions.  How can I configure CouchDB from my nodejs app?

I would like to:

- **Stop admin party and create an admin with a password.** I found that the web client makes a `PUT` request to `http://localhost:5984/_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/admins/<username>` with password in payload, but I would like to do it using express-pouchdb, so HTTP is not possible
- **Create users roles** I would like to set up several roles
- **Set up permissions** which roles can update which databases, what databases are readable by who etc...

Please note that I can't do direct http requests to CouchDB, since **I'm using `pouch-db-express` in my node app** to serve the db to the client, and I would like my express app to configure the couchDB instance managed by pouchdb-express

Answer (score 2):

1. **Stop admin party and create an admin with a password**

   I'm pretty sure the only way to interact with the `_config` endpoint is with HTTP, as I see no config plugin on the [plugins page](https://pouchdb.com/external.html).  Even if there was a plugin, it would use HTTP. Is there some reason HTTP is actually *not possible*?  Or you just don't want to use it?
2. **Create users roles**

   The [PouchDB authentication plugin](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) can do this for you.
3. **Set up permissions**

   The authentication plugin also gives you access to the `_security` endpoint for this.  Then you'll also need to create the appropriate design documents, using the standard [put()](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document) API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no direct way to do 1. I find that a node application that does HTTP calls on itself might lead to bugs and is kinda bad, but maybe I could first start the the pouchdb server on a standalone app, listening to `localhost` on a  random port, and then using my app configure it to stop admin party. What do you think?

Comment: Also, the pouchdb authentication plugin needs to do http calls, so I might need to do it in the configure part where I run the standalone server

Comment: @Vinz243: Its a _super simple_ HTTP request. I usually do it from a bash script with curl.  I don't know any reason why doing it in node should be especially error-prone.

Comment: Everything PouchDB does to talk to CouchDB is via HTTP calls. Every communication with CouchDB is via HTTP.

Comment: I understand, just using request module, but I don't want to make my server accessible during configuration time and I still don't like an http server making request on itself seems like a snake that bites its own tail

Comment: It's rare that you shouldn't end the admin party yourself before exposing it to your app.  The only exceptions I can think of is when you're distributing an entire OS, or in a CI environment. What is your exact situation that you're needing to programatically set up an admin account?

Comment: It's a self hosted nodejs server with a single page react app server + my database. I don't want users to have to spend hours setting up CouchDB. I'm not against ending the admin party in my app, I just don't want the frontend to be able to do so - or malevolent person - since the server should be accessible from the internet

Comment: Perhaps you should consider ending the admin party via the config file. Then you don't have to do it with node, and there's no chance for an outside party to gain access before it's configured.